# Get specific items values from a dictionary key

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have this table (just few rows) that is **loaded to a dictionary**.

[image]

I have a this **class module** 'clsTicket'

```
Public Field As String
Public row As Long
Public cell As String
Public Tabs As String
Public Required As String
```

This function **shows all the items for the key**, ind this case 'Ticket_Field3'

```
Call getDictKeyValuesAll(oDict, "Ticket_Field3")

Function getDictKeyValuesAll(oDict As Object, key As Variant) As Object
    ' Checks for the key exists
    If Not oDict.Exists(key) Then Exit Function

    Dim rgOut As Range
    Set rgOut = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

    Dim oTicket As clsTicket

    Set oTicket = oDict(key)
    With oTicket
        ' Write out the values
        rgOut.Cells(1, 1).Value = key
        rgOut.Cells(1, 2).Value = .row
        rgOut.Cells(1, 3).Value = .cell
        rgOut.Cells(1, 4).Value = .Tabs
        rgOut.Cells(1, 5).Value = .Required
    End With

    Set getDictKeyValuesAll = oDict
End Function
```

So far so good and it works as expected.

Now I would like to make a new **function to return just a few items**, not all items. I thought of using a ParamArray and try to get the values for "**Row**" and "**Cell**" for the key "**Ticket_Field3**". I tried to create the function below with a For loop, but I don't know how to get to each item specifically.

**Any suggestion?**

```
Call ShowDictKeyValues(oDict, "Ticket_Field3", "Row", "Cell")

Function getDictKeyValues(oDict As Object, key As Variant, ParamArray arrValues() As Variant) As Object
    ' Checks for the key exists
    If Not oDict.Exists(key) Then Exit Function

    Dim rgOut As Range
    Set rgOut = wsTicket.Range("A2")

    Dim oTicket As clsTicket
    Set oTicket = oDict(key)

    Dim vArg As Variant, icount As Integer
    For icount = 0 To UBound(arrValues)
        vArg = arrValues(icount)
        rgOut.Cells(1, icount + 1).Value = oDict.Item(vArg)
    Next icount
End Function
```

Comment: pass `"Row", "Cell"` as `Array("Row", "Cell")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as @Scott Holtzman has already mentioned, you can pass `Array("Row", "Cell")` to `getDictKeyValues` instead.  So you can replace `ParamArray arrValues() As Variant` with `arrValues As Variant`.

```
Function getDictKeyValues(oDict As Object, key As Variant, arrValues As Variant) As Object
```

Then you can use `CallByName` to return the values for each of the specified property names for the class object.

```
CallByName(oTicket, arrValues(iCount), VbGet)
```

By the way, since you're not actually returning anything, you can change your function to a sub.

**Called Procedure**

```
Sub getDictKeyValues(oDict As Object, key As Variant, arrValues As Variant)
    ' Checks for the key exists
    If Not oDict.Exists(key) Then Exit Sub

    Dim rgOut As Range
    Set rgOut = wsTicket.Range("A2")

    Dim oTicket As clsTicket
    Set oTicket = oDict(key)

    Dim iCount As Integer
    For iCount = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)
        rgOut.Cells(1, iCount + 1).Value = CallByName(oTicket, arrValues(iCount), VbGet)
    Next iCount

End Sub
```

**Call to Procedure**

```
Call getDictKeyValues(oDict, "Ticket_Field3", Array("Row", "Cell"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you. Domenic, I am starting to work more often with classes  and I didn't new 'CallByName'!!!